# Disable kwallet popups from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, kde, password-management

I've edited `~/.kde/share/config/kwalletrc` and added

```
[Auto Deny]
kdewallet=Chromium
```

In the KDE Wallet Configuration in system settings I've unchecked "Enable the KDE wallet subsystem". This also seems to add:

```
[Auto Deny]
kdewallet[$d]
```

However I'm still getting a popup when I visit my first page in google chrome. How can I stop it?

I've noticed there are actually two locations for wallets. One in `~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet/` and one in `~/.local/share/kwalletd/`. At one point when I changed the KDE colour theme I noticed the popup for chrome was different to the GUI I got through system settings. There's also a duplicate
KDE Wallet Configuration I can get by running `kwalletmanager`->Settings->Configure Wallet where I get the same options but their own set of values. Even after unchecking "Enable the KDE wallet subsystem" here as well I still get a popup from chrome. What's going on with the mess of multiple config locations and settings pages?

Comment: You are using KDE 5 (Plasma 5) right? The `~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet/` location is the old one that is migrated to `~/.local/share/kwalletd/` and should not be in use. For the same reason, the setting in ~/.kde/` is not honored... and note that your system can have both KWallet for KDE 4 and KDE 5 installed, complicating things even further.

Comment: Yes, I'm running 5. Can I remove the old one and all its configs? I guess chrome is using that instead.

Comment: It would not help I think, if you remove the old one it would appear as if no wallet has ever been made and then it would prompt you to create one. I think that @RobW's proposed solution works better (and is actually what you mean).

Comment: Ideally, I wouldn't have two version of the same thing, chrome would use the latest one and I could choose to disable it system wide the regular way (or for that matter, use it).

Comment: kde5: look in ~/.config for kwalletrc

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can completely disable the KWallet backend by adding the following command-line flag to Chrome: `--password-store=basic`

For instance (if you're using Ubuntu's Chromium build), edit `/etc/chromium-browser/default` (system-wide) or `~/.chromium-browser.init` (per-user) and add the flag to `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`. E.g.:

```
# Default settings for chromium-browser. This file is sourced by /bin/sh from
# /usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Options to pass to chromium-browser
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--password-store=basic"
```

If you're using ArchLinux's Chromium build, edit `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf` and add:

```
--password-store=basic
```

Comment: Where would be a good place to put this (so that it works with KDE shortcuts, `xdg-open`, when I type `google-chrome` in the terminal, etc.)? Is there a config somewhere?

Comment: @jozxyqk I've updated my answer. The answer applies ot Ubuntu and ArchLinux, if you use another OS, then the exact method might be different.

Comment: I couldn't find a similar place on fedora, but I found `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` and added `--password-store=basic` to the exec command at the bottom of the script. Seems to work. Thanks very much!

Comment: On Debian Jessie (8) I installed this file to `/etc/chromium.d/no-kwallet`

Comment: For vivaldi in `/opt/vivaldi/vivaldi`.

Answer (score 22):

**No matter what distro you're on this might work.**

Open "google-chrome" file with a text editor (I used kate <3)

```
kdesu kate /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

Paste this at the end of file with quote sign

> **"--password-store=basic"**

So it must look like this

```
else
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@" "--password-store=basic"
fi
```

SAVE AND EXIT. DONE!

(I tried it on OpenSUSE Thumbleweed with success! :D)

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 16.04 too. You also need to set google on hold `apt-mark hold google-chrome-stable`, because any update will remove that setting. They are not a fair company.

Comment: Won't it be reverted during the package upgrade?

Answer (score 10):

[I found a simple solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1560478#p1560478), that works a 100% of the time, on any version of KDE:

> I couldn't find any way to get kwallet off my system. There are some dependency issues and pacman won't let you remove the package.
>   However I managed to avoid the irritating pop ups.
>   First you need to remove any existing wallet. Delete the files under ~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet/.
>
> Next time you do anything that interests Kwallet, it will pop up again. But this time it will ask you for an encryption method, blowfish or gpg. Select blowfish and when asked for a password, provide an empty password.
>
> It won't ask for password anymore.
>   This method worked for me on kwallet 5.13. Hopefully it will work for you too.

Comment: You found this solution where?  You need to link to the source.

Comment: no, it doesn't work, deleted ~/.kde/... as its written here, restarted chrome and it still start popup kwallet nightmare

Comment: @stiv, as Lekensteyn [said](/q/994551#comment1374335_994551), KDE config paths changed some time ago, so maybe you need to delete another directory. Still, I don't say this recipe work, I haven't tried it.

Comment: @stiv, I've checked: for me it works, just choose a blowfish + empty password. And BTW there's no need to delete any files manually, just start `kwalletmanager5` and click “File” / “Delete Wallet…” in the menu.

Comment: For me it was this directory: `/.local/share/kwalletd/` - but then it worked, thanks, I guess...

Comment: It swallowed the tilde, the directory is in `/home/username/.local/share/kwalletd/` (I'm on fedora GNOME)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution to this Problem got served by the later KDE Plasma Versions. I currently use Version 5.12.7.

**1.** Go to: 
System Settings -> Account Details (Personalization) -> KDE
    Wallet

**2. Uncheck the Box "Enable the KDE wallet subsystem"**

**3.** Apply

Comment: it doesn't work, it says: the module Account details is not valid configuration module

Comment: it worked for me though.

Comment: This worked for me on Debian GNU/Linux 10, KDE plasma 5.14.5.  Initially, I did not see the "Enable the KDE wallet subsystem" option. But it showed up once I installed the kwalletmanager package.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this one out in the KWalletManager by creating a new wallet named `test` and replacing the `.salt` file from the existing wallet named `kdewallet`, with the `.salt` file of the newly created wallet `test`.

So

```
cd /home/'username'/.kde4/share/apps/kwallet 
mv kdewallet.salt .kdewallet.salt;cp test.salt kdewallet.salt
```

And now the existing wallet named `kdewallet` has the password for the newly created `test` wallet.

Distro: Mageia 5.

Answer (score 0):

One way is just to give chrome a fake dbus socket (Also you will probably need to disable password manager... you can use Paster Password Manager as an alternative)

```
env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=none chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to just change KWallet's password to a blank one:

**KDE's Application Menu (or Launcher, etc.) > System > KWalletManager > Change Password... > OK > Yes**

This ends KWallet's password pop-ups when starting Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: There is no Change Password... menuitem there.